# Can a prop be reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am writing a component which receives data via a `prop`, modifies that data, and then `$emit` it back to the parent (upon its change, so it is also in `watched`).

**Can a `prop` be reactive?** Or, alternatively, how to assign a prop to a reactive property?

I tried to avoid this question by:

- having `props: ["receiveddata"]`
- defining a reactive property in `data` (say, `hello: ''`)
- in `mounted()` ensure that `this.hello = this.receiveddata`

I expected at that point `this.hello` to carry the content brought in by the `receiveddata` prop, and from that point on work on `this.hello` (that is: modify it, watch it and `$emit` it when relevant)

However, when looking at the values in DevTools I see that

- `this.hello` is undefined
- `this.receiveddata` correctly holds the data passed to the component

I conclude that, when in `mounted()`, the props values are not yet known (thus the `undefined` of `this.receiveddata`), this `undefined` is assigned to this.hello, and then later `this.receiveddata` gets populated (but it's too late for me).

In other words, I plugged my `this.hello = this.receiveddata` in the wrong place, but I do not really know where it could go elsewhere (I also tried to change `mounted()` to `created()`)

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding 100% but I think this is what you're after.

I typically use a computed property with a getter and a setter in this case.

```
props: {
  someProp: String,
},
computed: {
  somePropLocal: {
    get () {
      return this.someProp
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    },
  },
}
```

This way you can do this freely and the proper value will be emitted.

```
this.somePropLocal = 'Whatever'
```

Also, `somePropLocal` will be updated if the parent changes it directly as well.